# How do I restrict a Google search to a certain category?

Tags: google-search

I work with the programming language Scala. Unfortunately the name is also used in many other contexts. In [Google Insights](http://www.google.com/insights/search) I can restrict the search to a certain category. In the filter section I can choose the category `Computer & Electronics / Programming`.

When I tried using `category:foobar` in a normal Google search it gave me an error message:

> category: was dropped from your search because it is not supported for this type of search.

How to I filter by category in a normal Google search?

Comment: Have you tried adding some programming related terms to direct Google to the right category?

Comment: This is the approach I usually take. It's bearable when I'm searching for ruby related stuff because I only have to use it every no and then but the term scala is way more ambiguous so that basically every second search request fails to return the desired reults.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this two google search queries

- [scala category:Computer & Electronics / Programming](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&qscrl=1&q=scala+category%3AComputer+%26+Electronics+%2F+Programming&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=d1fbe4ebbd01a4ef-)
- [scala category:food](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&qscrl=1&q=scala+category%3Afood&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=1&cad=b)

and its working correctly.

Comment: Your links don't generate the error message but neither do they generate the expected result on my computer. When I open the upper one I get [this result](http://loopkid.net/files/google-search-with-category.png). As you can see Google searches for the terms of the category rather than filtering by them.

Answer (score 0):

Use `inurl:mediafire` or `-inurl:nasa` to limit search to terms with or excluded in the sites url